# PHP Laravel api sent json post with curl

Tags: php, laravel

My problem is as follows

I have a counter *api* and it uses *laravel*. I need to send a post as *json* to this *api*, but when I send without headers, `419` page returns as expired, when I send headers, I get a `csrf token missmatch` error. However, I take the *csrf* token from the meta and put it in the headers.

**I want to point out that I do not use Laravel, the api I will post is using Laravel.**

**My Code:**

```
<?php 
$data = 'JSON DATA'; 
$wow = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"laravel api url");

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($resultado);
$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');
for ($i = 0; $i < $tags->length; $i++) {
    $grab = $tags->item($i);
    if ($grab->getAttribute('name') == 'csrf-token') {
        $token = $grab->getAttribute('content');
    }
}

ob_start();      // prevent any output
curl_exec ($ch); // execute the curl command
ob_end_clean();  // stop preventing output

curl_close ($ch);
unset($ch);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"LARAVEL API URL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $wow);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN: '.$token.''));

$buf2 = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

echo htmlentities($buf2);
?>
```

Comment: Why not just exclude that specific route from even needing a CSRF?

Comment: @Ron because this time I get the 419 page expired error.

Comment: 419 is exactly due to CSRF ..

Comment: @Ron I guess that way because when I delete the csrf line through the headers, I get 419.

Comment: You can declare in Laravel, that a specific route is not even checked for CSRF.. once you do that, there cannot be a 419 error... as there's not token to expire..

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: @Ron So what kind of code should I run? Can I get help from you?

Comment: see my answer below :)

Comment: @Ron I want to point out that I do not use Laravel, the api I will post is using Laravel.

Comment: a specific URL which is built in Laravel will be the receiver of the POST request, correct?

Comment: @Ron yes i will send my post url laravel correct.

Comment: and for that URL, where Laravel will be expecting the incoming data, that route, can be excluded via the answer I added below.

Comment: @Ron Can you send me a code sample? I don't understand because

Comment: What is the url to which you do the POST?

Comment: @Ron Can you send me the name of discord to send you url or it could be a different platform.

Comment: @Ron 
I sent you via gmail.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable `CSRF token` completely for a specific `route`, if that makes sense for your app.

Check [the DOCs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris) and edit `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar',
        'http://example.com/foo/*',
    ];
}
```